# Sum prime numbers in C

Tags: c

I have written a little program in C to calculate the sum of all prime numbers between 0 and 100. But the sum is wrong.

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    int main()
    {
     int i,a,count,add =0;
     printf("Prime numbers between 0 and 100 is : \n");
     for (i=1;i<100;i++)
     {
         count=0;
             for (a=1;a<=i;a++)
             {
                if (i%a==0)
                    count++;

             }
         if (count==2)
             printf("%d ",i);
             add = add + count;

     }

     printf("The sum of prime numbers %d ",add);
     return 0;
    }
```

Why I can not calculate the sum of prime numbers with this code: `add = add + count;`?

Comment: Don't you mean even numbers?

Comment: Look closely what you're adding  to `add`. And you forgot the `{}` for the `if (count==2)` condition.

Comment: This looks more like an attempt to count these numbers, not to sum them.

Comment: **Read the documentation of your C compiler (e.g. [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/)...) and of your debugger (e.g. [GDB](https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/)).** Compile with all warnings and debug info, e.g. with `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g` if using GCC. **Read also [this C reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c)**

Comment: Seems to work for 1 by accident.

Answer (score 1):

You should sum `i` instead of `count` :

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
 int i,a,count,sum =0;
 printf("Prime numbers between 0 and 100 is : \n");
 for (i=1;i<100;i++)
 {
     count=0;
     for (a=1;a<=i;a++)
     {
        if (i%a==0) count++;
     }
     if (count==2) {  //<== braces are required here
         printf("%d ", i);
         sum += i;
     }
 }
 printf("\nThe sum of prime numbers is %d \n", sum); //==> 1060
 return 0;
}
```